# Deliveries to Azure Function subscriber fails after slot swap

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

We have a Custom Event Grid Topic that is connected to an Azure Function (event trigger).
Works perfectly... until we do a deployment to the "staging" deployment slot and then swap the slots.
From that point Event Grid reports delivery failures.

I can use Postman to manually trigger the Azure Function, so I know the code is working properly.

If I disconnect the subscriber and reconnect with the exact same settings, the service is restored.

I feel like this is a bug somewhere but I don't understand how the Event Grid would even know that the slot swap has happened.  All the URLs, settings and behaviour are the same across the slots.

Is this a known issue? I may have to deploy directly to the production slot, which I'm not that keen on.

**ADDENDUM**: Might be material and might not; this particular function is on a Premium Consumption host that is attached to a VNet to allow it access to protected resources peered in.  From Visual Studio I am unable to attach and debug (I can with all my other functions) as I get an error to do with firewalls.  It's not clear whether this is material to my issue or not, so just adding it for completeness.  Remember that using Postman I can manually trigger the function.

Comment: Could you post the Event Grid reports delivery failures?

Comment: Are you using an *AzureFunction* or *Webhook* endpointType in the subscription?

Comment: The AEG is integrated with the App Service, see more details  https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/05/11/event-grid-integration.html and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-app-service

Comment: @RomanKiss Yes we are using the Azure Functions subscriber, not the webhook.

Comment: @DorisLv I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for - I will amend the question with a screen grab of what I'm seeing.

Comment: Actually I want to see the error page for more information... But you could look at my answer first, hope it help. @RichardHauer

Comment: @DorisLv thanks so much for following up; there is no "error page" that I am aware of. Only a graph as you have pictured and with Diagnostics enabled, a line in the table that says "a message was not delivered".  There's not a skerrick of actionable feedback to be found.

Comment: @RichardHauer in the case of AzureFunction endpointType, where the destination is based on the logical endpoint such as a resourceId, you shouldn't have any problem during the swapping slots when the **logical endpoint** (resourceId) is the same.

Comment: @RomanKiss  yes that's what I would have thought too, and in most cases everything works fine, and yet in this case... bang. In fact, when using the "Advanced editor" to define the subscription endpoint in the portal, you can see the resource name reference, that doesn't contain any guids or any reason to make one think EG would even notice a slot sway

Answer (score 0):

Actually the reconnect is not required. I reproduce your issue with different name functions when swapping slots.

Then I change the two function name to be same, and test the scenario, function triggered successfully.

The point is, **make sure your function name in staging slot is same as production slot**, so the event subscription would found it with same endpoint.

**Event Subscription:**
[image]
**Production slot:**
[image]
**Staging slot:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for running your experiment Doris.  The code is actually exactly the same in both slots.  Deployments are part of our CI/CD and this is one component in a big set, so sometimes it gets deployed because we can't easily determine whether we need to deploy it or not.   In this particular case, we have deployed literally identical code, so every conceivable aspect is the same.  The only thing that changed was that we swapped the slots.

Comment: I should reiterate, we have other Functions that are deployed exactly the same way, but do not exhibit this sort of issue.

Comment: Do you mean your other functions also triggered by event grid and when you do swap operation, they did not exhibit this sort of issue? @RichardHauer

Comment: that is correct.  I have several other Azure Functions connected up to the Event Grid.  This is the only one that has failures. If I delete the subscription and recreate it, it seems to work for a while. Without any error messages I've no idea if the issue is in my code or if this is an Azure issue.

Comment: Till now, we can generate the reason is about Vnet, but I don't know a lot of that, you could ask another question about whether Vnet influence endpoint or not. @RichardHauer And for solving the disconnection, maybe reconnect is the best way.